# Emacsify OSX throughout: word-forward (⌥ + F) and word-backward (⌥ + B) instead of 'special characters'?

Tags: macos

Yes, the OSX already supports <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> for moving the cursor word-backward and word-forward, but reaching for arrow keys is annoying. So, why not rather have <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> do this? I mean, not once have I (intentionally) wrote the integral sign ∫ with <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (apart from now).

In short, I'd rather have Emacs-like behavior (not just, say, <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for character-forward) throughout the OSX.

---

Related question: [Stop using Mac keyboard Option as a modifier to character](https://superuser.com/questions/151373/stop-using-mac-keyboard-option-as-a-modifier-to-character)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "^ " = setMark:;
  "^/" = undo:;
  "^l" = selectParagraph:;
  "^u" = deleteToBeginningOfParagraph:;
  "^w" = deleteToMark:;
  "^x" = {
    "^x" = swapWithMark:;
    "^m" = selectToMark:;
  };
  "^V" = pageDownAndModifySelection:;
  "~@" = selectWord:;
  "~b" = moveWordBackward:;
  "~c" = (capitalizeWord:, moveForward:, moveForward:);
  "~d" = deleteWordForward:;
  "~f" = moveWordForward:;
  "~l" = (lowercaseWord:, moveForward:, moveForward:);
  "~r" = centerSelectionInVisibleArea:;
  "~u" = (uppercaseWord:, moveForward:, moveForward:);
  "~v" = pageUp:;
  "~w" = (deleteToMark:, setMark:, yank:, swapWithMark:);
  "~B" = moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:;
  "~F" = moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:;
  "~V" = pageUpAndModifySelection:;
}
```

`DefaultKeyBinding.dict` doesn't work in some applications like Xcode or Firefox. Methods that use the kill ring remove formatting from rich text. Key combinations that enter dead key states (like option-u in the U.S. keyboard layout) cannot be reassigned.

See also http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/KeyBindings/Emacs%20Opt%20Bindings.dict. `transposeWords:` doesn't work in most applications. `openDocument:` and `saveDocument:` don't work in applications that use auto-save, and `performClose:` doesn't work everywhere either.

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html or http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html for more information.

### KeyRemap4MacBook

One option is to enable settings in the predefined [Emacs mode group](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/emacs_mode.xml):

[image]

Another option is to save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>EMACSMODEIGNORE</appname>
    <equal>com.gnu.Emacs</equal>
    <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
    <equal>com.googlecode.iterm2</equal>
    <equal>com.vmware.fusion</equal>
    <prefix>com.vmware.proxyApp.</prefix>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>emacs</name>
    <identifier>private.emacs</identifier>
    <not>EMACSMODEIGNORE</not>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::P, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::N, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::B, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::P, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::N, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::B, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::B, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_OPTION</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_OPTION</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::B, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::D, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE, VK_OPTION</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::V, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::PAGEUP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::V, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::PAGEUP, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::V, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::PAGEDOWN, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::U, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::DELETE, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.

Change the [key codes](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) if you use a keyboard layout like Dvorak or Colemak.

See https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en or http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html for more information.

Comment: Amazing. Changing relatively low-level behavior and yet so easy. A leap closer to a OS paradise. Hopefully there is even better, 100 % working solution, otherwise this is the answer.

Comment: As you say, it doesn't work in all apps. Xcode, for one, won't budge to this `.dict` (but that can be "solved" with a custom keybinding, say, ⌘+B and ⌘+F). Still, very powerful to have Emacs-like behavior (almost) throughout the OS.

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook has an [emacs mode group](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/emacs_mode.xml) that changes for example ⌥F to ⌥→, but not when Terminal or Emacs is frontmost. You can customize it by creating a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) based on it. I think the real solution is to just get a keyboard with the arrow keys and modifier keys at better positions.

Comment: Lauri, how would you **override ^ + N** (which is now mapped to `moveDown:`, if I'm not mistaken) **to behave as a down-arrow** (`\UF701`)? This would then allow you to navigate through Google's autocompletion, as well as search results, without having to use the down-arrow.

Comment: @courteous The emacs mode in KeyRemap4MacBook does that. It's not possible in a keylayout file or with DefaultKeyBinding.dict.

Comment: Perfect! I apologize for not heeding the advice earlier. :) Well, almost perfect: **how would you select a word?** ⇧+⌥+B prints out some character (while one would want it to select the previous word).

Comment: Got the ⇧+⌥+B to also select the previous word; (I think) enabling `Option + BF to Option Left/Right` did the trick. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @courteous I added that to the answer as well. I have `"~w" = selectWord:;` in [my DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://lri.me/keybindings.html).

Comment: If by any chance you might also know [how to use AltGr (right-Alt key) as an ⌥ key?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72106/the-ms-natural-keyboard-4000-use-right-alt-altgr-as)

Comment: It seems `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` option does not work in El-Capitan anymore, I tried to follow https://superuser.com/questions/1340224/how-to-enable-emacs-keybindings-on-macos-globally or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119639/emacs-key-bindings-on-other-programs but failed. I guess the changes in OSX version are big since creators of KeyRemap4MacBook (now Karabiner) had to rewrite "Karabiner as Karabiner-Elements-11.0.0 from scratch due to kernel architecture changes in macOS Sierra".