# Cannot differentiate between LEFT ⌘ (0x37) and RIGHT ⌘ (0x36) keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, microsoft

I would like to **swap the right-<kbd>⌘</kbd> key with the right-<kbd>⌥</kbd> key**.

[image: Microsoft Natural 4000]

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/)'s `EventViewer` shows that <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key acts as the *left*-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (`Command_L` in `EventViewer`), whereas I'd like to be the *right*-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (`Command_R`).

This is what it look like in `EventViewer`: first 2 lines are from left-<kbd>⌘</kbd>, next 2 lines are from right-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (with the same **`0x37`** code):
[image]

**How can I get the right-<kbd>⌘</kbd> key to register as `Command_R` (`0x36`) instead of `Command_L` (`0x37`)?**

## About the keyboard

It's the `Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000` with its drivers installed and setup like this:
[image]

I'll try my luck with uninstalling the drivers (which don't cause kernel panics anymore, as described [here](http://david.rothlis.net/keyboards/microsoft_natural_osx/)).

Comment: What kind of keyboard are you using?

Comment: @DanielLawson, it's a `Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000`; I'll put it (back) into question.

Comment: It looks like the Op answered his/her own question.  "Courteous", please mark your answer as the Answer and/or remove the Bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't it try this before? *Removing* Microsoft's drivers was the solution! Right-ALT now acts as `Option_R` out-of-the-box (and isn't affected by swapping CMD/ALT with OPTION/Windows key on the left side).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I misunderstood the question, but did you, um, try [remapping them](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en#examples)?

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Swap Command_L and Command_R </name>
    <identifier>private.swap_command_l_and_r</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

If the problem is that you are not using a Mac keyboard and both L and R are sending the same Keycode, then, as stated in the [KeyRempap4MacBook FAQ](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/faq.html.en):

> If you are using [non-Apple] vendor's keyboard drivers, KeyRemap4MacBook may not work properly. Please uninstall vendor's keyboard drivers.

Comment: Yes, I did try to remap them by ticking checkmark next to `Commmand_R to Option_R` option in `KeyRemap4MacBook`'s frontend ... which surely translates into something alike your XML (and which also works on a MacBook Air). You're also correct on the 2nd part: the keyboard is the `Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000`, with its drivers installed (I've updated the question).