# How do you disable VI-like behavior in macOS terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, command-line

When I open a terminal and type

```
asdf asdf asdf asdf
```

And hit `control-u`, the line gets wiped. If I type that line again, but then use `option-left` to skip a word back, then `control-u` doesn't wipe the line at all.

To begin with I was having trouble with `option-right` not skipping words forward. So I thought I fixed it with these terminal settings. But honestly I have no idea what these ascii codes do, and what state my terminal gets into.

Do ascii codes that skip words forward and back without breaking the terminal exist? What are they?

[image: mac terminal keyboard settings]

FYI Looking at `set -o` I see that VI mode is off.

```
macbookpro% set -o | grep ' on'
combiningchars        on
interactive           on
login                 on
shinstdin             on
```

Comment: It’s actually [Emacs behavior](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/378477/119271), not `vi`  What you have to do is change the key bindings. See  if  this  gets  you  in  the  right  direction. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/85757/119271

Comment: It's actually a readline binding within `bash`, so you can change the behaviour in `.inputrc`. Or just start to get used to `C-y` to get the line back if you delete it by accident :-)

Comment: I tried this again in bash and I could use ctrl-u and option-arrow freely, so the profile config is working fine. I suspect it might be a binding problem in zsh. EDIT - I needed to set the option-right back to \033f for it to work well in bash.

Comment: It seems that `bindkey -r "^[" vi-cmd-mode` completely disables the skipping words functionality 

Answer (score 1):

I found a lot of clues here: https://coderwall.com/p/a8uxma/zsh-iterm2-osx-shortcuts

This is what I put in my `.zshrc` to fix things.

```
bindkey "\033f" forward-word
bindkey "\033b" backward-word
bindkey "\033[H" beginning-of-line
bindkey "\033[F" end-of-line
```

Alongside these terminal keyboard settings:

[image: MacOS default terminal keyboard settings]

For some reason, the control (^) key modifier can be set, but does not activate the codes in the terminal. So I'm only using option and shift.

I found a similar solution here which mentioned you can see the key codes by running `cat`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382499/looking-for-altleftarrowkey-solution-in-zsh

Initially I used whatever key codes I wanted. That was a mistake, because even though they worked on my local mac, they didn't work when I SSH-ed into a linux machine. Using `less /etc/inputrc` on the remote bash I found these existing shortcuts:

```
# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Also, my local bash had different settings. To find those out I used

```
bash-3.2$ bind -p | grep of-line
"\C-a": beginning-of-line
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\C-e": end-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
```

Which made me settle on the terminal keyboard settings you see at the top. Because they worked in all 3 settings (local zsh, local bash, remote bash).