# All text boxes : The opposite of ctrl+v (like in emacs)

Tags: unix, emacs, text-input

I like using <kbd>ctrl + v</kbd> on mac for jumping with the cursor to the next screen - something like <kbd>page down</kbd> but the cursor moves too.

Do you know any way to do the opposite - jumping to the previous screen - like <kbd>page up</kbd> but also with the cursor moving?

I'd love a universal solution - i.e. working in all text boxes.

UPDATE: I've refreshed my mind that there's a key binding in terminals that does exactly what I want and that's <kbd>meta + v</kbd> but that doesn't work in all Cocoa text boxes as <kbd>ctrl + v</kbd> does.

Comment: Maybe `ctrl+^` ?

Comment: You many want to rephrase your question to specify which app to which you are referring. I can infer you are speaking about emacs, but others may not.

Comment: @Dave Thanks, I edited that, I was thinking of an all-around solution that would work in all Cocoa-based text boxes. In terminal I'd use `meta + v` as suggested in one answer.

Comment: @mouviciel I tried that, and it doesn't seem to work. Is it supposed to work only in Terminal or in all text boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⌥⇞ and ⌥⇟ (option-page up and option-page up) also move the caret, like ⌃V.

You can make ⌥V scroll a page up and move the caret by saving a property list like this as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "~v" = pageUp:;
}
```

It is also possible to make the page up and page down keys move the caret:

```
{
  "\UF72C" = pageUp:;
  "\UF72D" = pageDown:;
}
```

The `pageUp:` and `pageDown:` methods don't do anything in web views (including Safari) or in Numbers though.

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html or http://lri.me/keybindings.html for more information.

You can also use KeyRemap4MacBook to remap ⌥V to ⇞, or ⇞ and ⇟ to ⌥⇞ and ⌥⇟. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68716/emacsify-osx-throughout-word-forward-f-and-word-backward-b-instead/71087#71087).

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that before but I thought it didn't work in 10.8. I think `⌥ + ⇞` and `⌥ + ⇟` is acceptable. It works for me in Pages. And I was after moving the caret actually.

Comment: Okay, now `⌥ + V` does scroll the page up, but I had to change layout from U.S. Extended to just U.S.

Answer (score 1):

The Emacs command for page up is Meta-v.  Unfortunately, Cocoa only seems to implement the Control-key commands, not commands with Meta.  (Alt is used for special or international characters.  Alt-v gives me a square root key on my keyboard layout.)

Comment: Meta on OSX is `Esc` by default. `Esc+v` works.

Comment: `meta+v` works only in terminal for me (`esc+v` or `opt+v`).