# Option + b results in ∫ Instead of Jumping Back a Word

Tags: ui, text-input

Just got a new MacBook Pro and can't seem to recall how to get the emacs bindings to work in the general MacOSX GUI.  On my old Mac `Option + b` went back a word and `Option + f` went forward a word.  `Option + d` deleted a word.

Still works fine in the terminal.

For Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162896/emacs-on-mac-os-x-leopard-key-bindings

Comment: This exact issue prompted my friend to switch to Vi mode: https://catonmat.net, see this cheat sheet: https://catonmat.net/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 7):

Option-B has always been mapped to ∫ in OS X, and option-B has never been mapped to jumping back a word in emacs. What you're thinking of is the *meta*-B shortcut, which is only sometimes mapped to the option key depending on the app. In the Terminal you can enable it by going to Preferences > Settings > Keyboard and checking "Use option as meta key".

You're also probably confusing it with the Ctrl-B keyboard shortcut to jump back one *character*. That's the emacs shortcut that is available in all OS X apps. You can jump back one word using option-Ctrl-B, delete one word using option-Ctrl-D, etc.

If you want to use option-B and the other emacs shortcuts across all apps, you'll need to install some additional software for triggering the emacs behaviors when pressing the OS X keyboard combinations, as seen in this thread:

[Emacsify OSX throughout: word-forward (⌥ + F) and word-backward (⌥ + B) instead of 'special characters'?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68716/emacsify-osx-throughout-word-forward-%E2%8C%A5-f-and-word-backward-%E2%8C%A5-b-instead)